# Split string (with variable number of value) into different columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would like to split a string with a variable number of values into different columns.

I know that It exist a solution 'PIVOT' but I'm not sure this will works when the number of value is not the same.

Here is an example:

```
+-----+-----------+
| Key |   Value   |
+-----+-----------+
|   1 | A,B,C     |
|   2 | A,B,C,D   |
|   3 | A,B,C,D,E |
+-----+-----------+
```

Result:

```
+-----+------+------+------+------+------+
| Key | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Col5 |
+-----+------+------+------+------+------+
|   1 | A    | B    | C    |      |      |
|   2 | A    | B    | C    | D    |      |
|   3 | A    | B    | C    | D    | E    |
+-----+------+------+------+------+------+
```

I know that there is at least 1 value and maximum 5 values in the string, so I have to generate 5 columns and filing it accordingly.

Comment: Only via dynamic SQL. Any *particular* query always returns a result with a fixed "shape" - the *number of columns*, their names and types. (Dynamic SQL doesn't break this idea - it instead is a way of constructing new queries dynamically)

Answer (score 2):

Use a bit of XML querying:

```
DECLARE @mockup TABLE (
    [key] INT
    ,[value] VARCHAR(max)
    );

INSERT INTO @mockup
VALUES 
 (1,'A,B,C')
,(2,'A,B,C,D')
,(3,'A,B,C,D,E')

;WITH Splitted
AS (
    SELECT [key]
        ,[value]
        ,CAST('<x>' + REPLACE([value], ',', '</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) AS Parts
    FROM @mockup
    )
SELECT [key]
    ,Parts.value(N'/x[1]', 'varchar(max)') AS Col_1
    ,Parts.value(N'/x[2]', 'varchar(max)') AS Col_2
    ,Parts.value(N'/x[3]', 'varchar(max)') AS Col_3
    ,Parts.value(N'/x[4]', 'varchar(max)') AS Col_4
    ,Parts.value(N'/x[5]', 'varchar(max)') AS Col_5
FROM Splitted;
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: This is a good solution only if you have a maximum number of columns to return. If the maximum number of columns is unknown when writing the query, then dynamic SQL must be used.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I agree with you, but apparently the OP has a maximum of 5 columns to return

Comment: Correct, I didn't see that part in the question before you pointed that out.